# Make jQuery Slider Update element as it's moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would like my jQuery slider to update the numbers above it dynamically as the user moves the slider. Right now the numbers above only change when the slider is done moving.

Here is my code:

HTML >

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <div id="amount-money" class="slider-text left">$120000</div>
                <div id="amount-money-2" class="slider-text right">$10000000</div>
            </div>
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <div id="amount-bath" class="slider-text left">1 Bathroom</div>
                <div id="amount-bath-2" class="slider-text right">4 Bathroom</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <div class="slider-wrapper">
                    <div class="slider costSlider"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <div class="slider-wrapper">
                    <div class="slider bathSlider"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Javascript >

```
  // creating sliders for search
  $( ".costSlider" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 120000,
    max: 10000000,
    values: [ 120000, 10000000 ],
  });
  $( ".bathSlider" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    values: [ 1, 4 ],
  });

  $( ".costSlider" ).on( "slidechange", function( event, ui ){
    console.log(ui.values);
    $( "#amount-money" ).replaceWith('<div id="amount-money" class="slider-text left"> $' + ui.values[0]);
    $( "#amount-money-2" ).replaceWith('<div id="amount-money-2" class="slider-text right"> $' + ui.values[1]);
  });
  $( ".bathSlider" ).on( "slidechange", function( event, ui ){
    $( "#amount-bath" ).replaceWith('<div id="amount-bath" class="slider-text left">' + ui.values[0] + ' Bathroom');
    $( "#amount-bath-2" ).replaceWith('<div id="amount-bath-2" class="slider-text right"> ' + ui.values[1] + ' Bathroom');
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ought to be able to harness [the `slide` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide).

```
$( ".costSlider" ).on( "slide", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

Which is (emphasis mine)...

> ***Triggered on every mouse move during slide***. The value provided in the
>   event as `ui.value` represents the value that the handle will have as a
>   result of the current movement. Canceling the event will prevent the
>   handle from moving and the handle will continue to have its previous
>   value.